# SVN - Summary of conflicts: Skipped paths : 1

Tags: svn, command-line, version-control

I recently tried to do an **svn up** and got the following:

```
Conflict discovered in 'myapp/protected/config/myapp/mode_staging.php'
```

I was given a number of options and I (probably the wrong choice now) choose to [p] Postone.

Now when I try to run the svn up I get the following message everytime (plus the site itself has a white screen of death)

```
Skipped 'myapp/protected/config/myapp/mode_staging.php
At revision xxx.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
```

Clearly the mode_staging.php is the problem - what is the best/easiest way to resolves this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some uncommitted changes you have in mode_staging.php in your working copy conflict with incoming changes from the repository (which you get when running `svn update`). By choosing option [P], you've [instructed the client to postpone conflict resolution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.pending) so the file mode_staging.php has `C` (Conflicted) status in your working copy. You must resolve the conflict to solve the issue. For example, you can resolve the conflict by discarding changes you performed locally (i.e. by accepting changes from the repository). In such case you should run `svn resolve --accept=theirs-full` against the conflicted file.

See ["SVNBook | Resolve Any Conflicts"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve) for more information.

Comment: I have gone to the directory and tried 'sudo svn resolve --accept=theirs-full'
it gives me a svn: not enough arguments provided (any ideas what to do next?)

Comment: @zabs you have to run the command against mode_staging.php file

Comment: cheers thanks tried that & now I get the following: 
svn: warning: Tree conflicts can only be resolved to 'working' state; 'mode_staging.php' not resolved

Any ideas? (svn is tricky lol)

Comment: @Zabs, I guess that the file got removed in the repository while your working copy contains some uncommitted changes in this file. In such case, I suggest running `svn resolve --accept=working` against it.

Comment: BTW, I *strongly* suggest reading SVNBook chapter http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve The chapter spoon-feeds the topic.